# How to output objects to various coordinates of a powershell console window at the same time?

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have been using powershell on a win 10 environment for a few months now, so still new to powershell and am trying use the powershell console as a technical point of display, whereby it cycles/loops through various components of data and displays the information at various coordinates of the console window. The problem I have is it can only display the data from any one particular loop at any one time. I suspect a type of multithreading is going to be needed like runspaces or psjobs, but I believe they are both background functions and cant display data in real-time, so not sure if the console even supports this kind of request.
Perhaps there is another way of going about this

I have tried putting all my scripts and get- command under one loop but it doesnt provide the "look" and feel we are trying to achieve. I want to be able to use the entire window as realestate for outputing objects. I have looked at psjobs and runspaces but they seem to work in the background.

So the code presented should output the get-service ojbects and the get-process objects to the coordinates specified at the same time.

```
function OBJ1{
[console]::setcursorposition(60,120)
Get-Process
]}
function OBJ2{
[console]::setcursorposition(10,70)
Get-Service
]}
Workflow obj3
{ 
Parallel 
{ 
obj1
obj2
} 
} 
obj3
```

Instead the errors I get are:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : Exception calling "SetCursorPosition" with "2" argument(s): "The handle is invalid.
"
At obj3:20 char:20
+
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorCommand
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]

Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : Exception calling "SetCursorPosition" with "2" argument(s): "The handle is invalid.
"
At obj3:20 char:20
+
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorCommand
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]
```